# Rails add banner after iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

Currently, I have a list that displays a list item, for every vehicle within our database.

**Ex:**

```
= render partial: 'list_item', collection: (@vehicles && vehicles), as: :vehicle
```

What I want is simply to add a banner after every 10 cars.  (Out of probably, 100's of cars.)  What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David has the right idea, but is doing a lot of extra work. Rails does this for you. From [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables):

> Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called by the collection, named after the member of the collection followed by `_counter`. For example, if you're rendering `@products`, within the partial you can refer to `product_counter` to tell you how many times the partial has been rendered. This does not work in conjunction with the `as: :value` option.

In this case all you'd need to do is add this to your partial:

```
<% if list_item_counter % 10 == 0 %>
  <!-- Ad banner goes here -->
<% end %>
```

(Or you could invoke a helper method like David does.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a local variable in the code that you have pasted in your question to be used as an iterator.  Within the partial you can then use this type of logic:

```
<%= ad_helper_func if @iterator_var % 10 == 0 %>
<% @iterator_var += 1 %>
```

Comment: Thanks David, I see what you mean.  Also the point of using a Modulo didn't even occur to me.  Thanks for the help.  I'll accept when possible.